# Rounding Logic for decimal digits in java

Tags: java

I need the rounding logic in the following pattern..for 2.23 it should be 2.2 ,for 2.26 it should be 2.3... Please Help out

Comment: and whats about 2.25 ?

Comment: for 2.25 it should be 2.3

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. The principle on the site is to help user after they have shown their own effort to solve their problems. Such effort may be to search online with keywords like `java rounding`. See [ask] to improve your post please.

Comment: `Math.ceil` and `Math.floor `methods!! you can try

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double a = <ur NUmber>;
double roundOff = (double) Math.round(a*10)/10;
```

Hope this would help you. here 2.25 would be round off to 2.3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print, than use `printf` method, It has default rounding.

```
System.out.printf("%.1f", 2.23);
System.out.printf("%.1f", 2.26);
```

If you need rounding value for calculation than use `Math.round`

```
double newValue= (double)Math.round(value*10)/10;
```